# SP 2007 - Disable adding/deleting rows in a list's datasheet view but keep editing intact

Tags: 2007, list, datasheet

We often get requests to remove the users' ability to add/remove items from our sharepoint lists, while still allowing them to edit existing items. We've traditionally accomplished this by adding some custom javascript to hide the New/Delete buttons in the various list forms. Not pretty, but it works.

However, our latest request also asks that we do this even if the user clicks "Edit in Datasheet". They want to keep the datasheet view itself, and allow individual rows to be editable, but to disable adding/deleting new rows.

Is this possible?

Comment: Question was answered here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointgeneral/thread/81758203-3bbc-478e-9448-3b358745d11d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question was answered here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointgeneral/thread/81758203-3bbc-478e-9448-3b358745d11d

Basically we could create a custom permission level that allows editing, but prevents Add & Delete and then assign this permsision level to the users and/or groups.

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.